# Trouble translating Touch coordinates following device orientation change

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, rotation, coordinate-transformation

Ok the scenario is that I have a custom class which creates a view containing an image and handles all its own touch events. Occasionally I want to check if moving it would cause it to overlap another view on a parent view. So after the relevent touch event I call a method on the parent view passing it the last touch cordinate and return a BOOL. This works fine while the application remains in portrait orientation.

Problem is after rotating the device and all the images are auto-rotated for me the CGPoint being passed is now in a rotated coordinate system compared with the parent view and the CGRectContainsPoint method being called no longer works properly.

In my willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method I am adjusting the position of each custom view to improve the layout for the new orientation e.g.

```
view.frame = CGRectMake((view.frame.origin.x*1.5),(view.frame.origin.y/1.5),view.frame.size.width,view.frame.size.height);
```

I read that calling the setBound method would then reset the coordinate system:

```
[view setBounds:view.frame];
```

but this isn't making a difference in my case. I also tried tinkering with 'convertPoint:toView' but the values it was giving weren't making much sense either. I concluded it wouldn't work in the case where the coordinate system had been rotated?

Answer (score 1):

When your view is rotated (using the autorotate mechanism), iOS simply apply a `CGAffineTransform` to your view, to rotate its content.

So you should be able to retrieve the current CGAffineTransform applied to your UIView, then apply this CGAffineTransform to the point of your UITouch using `CGPointApplyAffineTransform` (probably after inverting the AffineTransform, to apply the inverse transformation to your point. Haven't tested this code, only writing this from memory)

```
UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint pt = [touch locationInView:self];
CGAffineTransform inverseTransform = CGAffineTransformInvert(self.transform);
CGPoint transformedPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(pt,inverseTransform);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have tried to implement this but didn't have much success. I put a break point in and looked at the values for the 'inverseTransform' but it doesn't seem to vary with the orientation of the screen?

Comment: Just to confirm, the transform of my main UIView nor any of subviews I'm interested in seem to change when I rotate the screen (a 1.0  b 0.0  c 0.0  d 1.0).

Comment: OK so maybe it's not the transform of the right view. Generally it's the transform of the view of your ViewController itself. If you can't find it, try investigating from the view back up to all its **superviews**.

Comment: My Hierarchy is the Window, TabbedViewController, UIView, customSubViews. From the UIView I have tried checking the transform of the parent and its (a 0.0 b 0.0 c 0.0 d 0.0) and doesnt change with rotation either. I'm seemingly out of views to check.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have my Mac near me right now to check myself, but it seems strange that none of your transforms are different from the Identity transform... I wonder how come you view can be rotated then?! Maybe try testing the CATransform of the layers of your view instead? I'll try to do some tests on my own If I got some time before the weekend

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Just tested it myself by creating an empty projet and implemented ```didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:``` to test the transform property after rotation. I *do* have a ```transform``` on my ```viewController.view``` when the autorotate takes place (```[1, 0, -0, 1, 0, 0]```=Identity when in Portrait mode, ```[0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]``` when in LandscapeRight mode). [You can view here](https://gist.github.com/1189893) the sample code I used. Anyway, when in landscape mode, width and height of your view are then swapped, that's probably the source of your issue.

Comment: Well this perplexing. I have added the NSLog into my didautorotate method of my view controller exactly as you've shown and in every orientation it logs [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]. I tried adding it to another viewcontroller in my tabbed bar that rotates but doesn't do any work off the back of an orientation change and I get the same thing. I again tried to check the window transform and no change there either. Until I can get the coordinate system rotated by 90 degrees (depending on the orientation) the question of the width and height being swapped or not isn't really relevant.

Comment: I appreciate the help you've tried to give me with this. Can you think of any reason why this transform isn't changing when the orientation is clearly changing (as the moethod is being called to produce the log)? Nothing in my code is trying to directly manipulate the view's transform (didn't even know about it until your answer). Additionally there has been no special implementation to create the rotation just returning TRUE from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in all my view controllers. I started the project in ios 3.2 and now working in the latest ios/xcode versions.

Comment: Is your view in a TabBarController? If so, at least for the purpose of testing, try to test it out of your TabBarController (e.g. in a new project using a NavigationController and not a TabBar). If you got a transform other than the Identity transform, the problem probably lies in the way the TabBarController works with autorotations?

Answer (score 0):

The view of root viewController always acts like portrait mode. You should insert a new view inside of the root one. And this new view will acts correctly, will give right size and coordinates according to Apple says.

for example ;

```
UIView *v = self;
while ([[v superview] superview] != NULL) {
    v = [v superview];
}

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:v];
```

touchPoint will be the correct one.