# CGRectMake did not work perfectly in landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

when I draw a UIView in landscape mode of ipad , it gives wrong width and wrong height,i have mentioned as follows

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

rightView.view.frame = CGRectMake(598, 700, 60, 171);
```

but width is very high,height is very low…any help please?

Answer (score 0):

When in landscape mode, as the frame is in the coordinates system of its parent view and the parent view has a CGAffineTransform applied (to apply the interface orientation), with and height are inverted.

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235788/trouble-translating-touch-coordinates-following-device-orientation-change/7236171#7236171) that also deals with related issues

Comment: so how can i give frame allocation? CGRectMake(x,y,hieght,width)..am i right??

Comment: Yep if it is really related to the fact that your interface orientation is rotated in landscape, that should do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

YOu may set frame like. it will give you a require result.

```
    CGRectMake(self.view.size.width-426 ,self.view.size.height-100 , self.view.size.width-366, self.view.size.height-497);
```

Answer (score 0):

just write below line
rightView.view.frame = CGRectMake(598, 700, 171, 60);